# WebapiAuthenticationError: An authentication error occurred while communicating with Spotify's Web API. Details: invalid_grant Invalid redirect URI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spotify, nodemon

I'm trying to make a clone of spotify. So for that I'm using spotify-web-api-node. But I'm getting the error as follow :

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/refresh', (req, res) => {
const refreshToken = req.body.refreshToken
console.log(refreshToken);
const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    clientId: 'My Client ID',
    clientSecret: 'My Client Secret ',
    refreshToken,
}) 

spotifyApi
    .refreshAccessToken()
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log('The access token has been refreshed');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.sendStatus(400)
    })
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
const code = req.body.code;
const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    clientId: 'My Client ID',
    clientSecret: 'My Client Secret',
})  

spotifyApi
    .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then(data => {
    res.json({
        accessToken: data.body.access_token,
        refreshToken: data.body.refresh_token,
        expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(400)
})
})

app.listen(3001)
```

useAuth.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

export default function useAuth(code) {
const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState()
const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState()
const [expiresIn, setExpiresIn] = useState()

console.log(refreshToken);

useEffect(() => {
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', {
    code,
}).then(res => {
    setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken)
    setRefreshToken(res.data.refreshToken)
    setExpiresIn(res.data.expiresIn)
    window.history.pushState({}, null, "/")
}).catch(() => {
    window.location = "/"
})
}, [code])

useEffect(() => {
if ( !refreshToken || !expiresIn ) return
const interval = setInterval(() => {
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/refresh', {
    refreshToken,
})
.then(res => {
    setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken)
    setExpiresIn(res.data.expiresIn)
})
.catch(() => {
    window.location = "/"
})
}, (expiresIn - 60) * 1000)

return () => clearInterval(interval)

}, [refreshToken, expiresIn])

return accessToken
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting :
WebapiAuthenticationError: An authentication error occurred while communicating with Spotify's Web API.
Details: invalid_grant Invalid redirect URI.

Answer (score 0):

With Create React App, your `index.js` file will most likely have `StrictMode` set by default with the `<React.StrictMode>` tag. In a development environment, React runs things twice in order to check for errors.

See the React [Strict Mode documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

It appeared that the Spotify Web API is trying to authenticate twice because of this side-effect, and doesn't like it. Removing the `<React.StrictMode>` tags fixed this issue for me.

A user by the name of Taslim Raza Ansari was the original commenter that pointed me in the right direction for the fix.

See this [video solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xcet6msf3eE&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified).